# Current Draw with Stepped Down Voltage

Tags: current, voltage-regulator

If I have a 24V source, and then step down the voltage to 5V. Then at this 5V level I draw 1 Amp, what current draw will this be on the 24V source. My gut tells me it's 5V/V24 * 1 Amp mathematically but is this true in real life?
Edit:
DC/DC converter

Comment: What kind of regulator are you using? Is it DC/AC?

Comment: DC/DC I appologize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you use to step down the voltage. If you use a switching regulator, you are mostly correct, less inefficiencies in the regulator.

On the other hand, if you use a linear regulator, you’ll see a 1 amp (plus inefficiencies) draw on the 24 volts.

In either case, the losses will show up mostly as heat. With the linear, the regulator will put out 19 watts of heat.

Answer (score 1):

You can't break conservation of energy, and you have losses, so basically:

Power In = Power Out + losses

So, if power out = 5V * 1A = 5W, then:

Power In = 5W + losses

If a regular DC/DC converter has ~80% efficiency, then losses = 5W * ~0.2 = ~1.25W

So, Power in = ~6.25W

~6.25W = 24V * I → I = ~6.25W/24V = ~260mA

In summary:

- 24V, 260mA in (6.25W)
- 5V, 1A out (5W)
- (~1.25W in losses)

Comment: ...... (Why did you abruptly stop?) ............. \$24V×I = ~6.25W \rightarrow  I = ~\frac{6.25W}{24V} ≃ 260 mA\$

Comment: @HarrySvensson -- oh man, I have no idea.. Thanks a lot for pointing that out, added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is true if you have a 100% efficient step-down converter. Probably the best you can get is 85% efficient - and that's when running at rated load. At a lighter load the efficiency will fall off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEtcD4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A linear regulator.*

Your worst option would be to use a linear regulator. It will act as resistance in the current path and waste 19/24 of the power.

[image]

*Figure 2. A plug-in 7805 switching regulator.*

You should be able to find a switching regulator or ready-made board to do the job. Have a look for 7805 switching regulator replacment and you should find something like that shown in Figure 2.

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to go to a datasheet for these sort of questions.  Not all manufacturers list input current.

But from [Traco Power DC/DC Datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/tsr1.pdf):

> **Input Specifications**
>
> Maximum input current (at Vin min. and 1 A output current) 1 A
>
> Model: TSR 1-2450
>
> Input voltage range: 6.5 – 36 VDC
>
> Output voltage: 5.0 VDC
>
> Output current max: 1.0A
>
> Efficiency typ. @Vin min.: 94%
>
> Efficiency typ. @Vin max.: 84%

So at Vin = 6.5V, efficiency is 94% when Iout = 1.0A then Iin = 1.0A.  It's probably slightly larger.

As Vin increases with Vout and Iout constant, efficiency decreases and Iin > Iout.

Most convertors have efficiencies between 75% and 98%.

In your case, Vin = 24V and Vout = 5V, so you'd be towards the bottom.  I'd guess Iin < 1.25A for Iout = 1A.